Why can Hamel basis represent vectors as finite sums?
A Hamel basis in an infinite dimensional linear space $L$ is a set $\{{e_w}\}\ , \ w\in W $ where any finite subset {$e_1, ... ,e_n$} must be linearly independent. Also there it must span $L$. What I don't seem to undertand is how can we say for sure that all vectors  $\forall x\in L$ can be represented as a finite linear combination of the Hamel basis?
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_ke_k$$

In general,  there is no notion of an infinite sum... that requires some topology. I suggest revisiting the proof that Hamel bases exist.

The definition of "span of $L$" is precisely the set of all linear combinations of finite subsets of $L$. So you know every vector can be represented as a finite linear combination because you are assuming that the set spans $L$, that is, that every vector in $L$ is a linear combination of a finite subset of ${e_w}_{w\in W}$.
